# Multiple ForeignKey keys in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

In pure SQL I can declare multiple foreign keys like:

```
ALTER TABLE available_routes  ADD FOREIGN KEY (client_id, site_id) REFERENCES sites(client_id, id);
```

I am trying to create model, that have some constrains. But can't understand how to do it:

```
mytable = Table ('mytable', metadata,
#...
Column('client_id', ForeignKey("clients.id"))
)
```

Comment: For which purpose you want to create model ? if you want to add constrains then I will help you, will provide you full sql statement along with foreign key and constrains, please specify requirements

Comment: It's a foreign key to a composite key, not "multiple foreign keys". That'd be multiple separate foreign keys.

Comment: Since you're using `Table` instead of a mapped class this is not quite an exact duplicate, but you'll find the answer here: [Relations on composite keys using sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504753/relations-on-composite-keys-using-sqlalchemy)