# SQLAlchemy query over multiple tables with joinedload

Tags: python, sql, join, select, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy with FastAPI to build an API.
So my current problem is, querying the data from the database.
I have multiple tables e.g. Table Header, Table Foo and Table Bar.

```
class Header(Base):
idno = Column(NUMBER, primary_key=True)
id_db = Column(NUMBER, primary_key=True)
authorization = Column(NUMBER)
```

```
class Foo(Base):
idno = Column(NUMBER, primary_key=True)
id_db = Column(NUMBER, primary_key=True)
idno_header = Column(NUMBER, Foreign_key(Header.idno))
id_db_header = Column(NUMBER, Foreign_key(Header.id_db))
nr = Column(NUMBER)
header = relationship('Header')


class Bar(Base):
idno = Column(NUMBER, primary_key=True)
id_db = Column(NUMBER, primary_key=True)
idno_foo = Column(NUMBER, Foreign_key(Bar.idno)
id_db_foo = Column(NUMBER, Foreign_key(Bar.id_db)
data = Column(NUMBER)
foo = relationship('Foo')
```

The result should contain all data from the tables. I tried to solve this with the joinedload() method but could not achieve any results.

I tried something like this:

```
query = db.query(Header).join(Foo).join(Bar).options(joinedload(Foo), joinedload(Bar)).filter(Bar.data == 2)
```

I tried replacing joinedload() with contains_eager() but could not achieve any results too.

How should i write my query to get the results ?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: The issue is probably that you are defining each `ForeignKey` separately. Looking at [this question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504753/relations-on-composite-keys-using-sqlalchemy), you should define it using  `__table_args__` and `ForeignKeyConstraint` to get the joins working in SQLAlchemy. I would ask **why** all your tables have composite primary keys, do you need it for some reason? In general they can be a pain to work with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @M.O.
I removed the ForeignKey and added ForeignKeyConstraint. But by querying `query = db.query(Header).join(Foo).join(Bar).options(contains_eager(Foo), contains_eager(Bar)).filter(Bar.data == 2)` I get an error message ` sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: mapper option expects string key or list of attributes`